# "Horror" movie involving a young girl who underwent some ritual as an infant, is neglected by her adoptive parents and bullied by other kids

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't quite remember the name of this movie, but I do remember watching it. The plot is as follows:

- The protagonist participated in some ritual as an infant in the beginning of the movie
- Her adoptive parents are neglectful towards her
- She is constantly bullied and harassed by other  children
- "Your parents are dead!"
- There are two scenes in the movie where she is transformed to some demon or monster of some kind

I would like to watch it again, I just don't remember the name. It came out sometime around 2015.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

This is the 2015 film [*June*](https://horrornews.net/102440/film-review-june-2015/).

> As the film opens, a baby girl is placed on a sort of sacrificial altar by a group of shroud wearing adults. Their leader cuts her hand open and drips blood on the child’s forehead, preparing to summon something. But at the last minute, the child is rescued from its predicament by one of the attendees, who then runs off with the baby. Cut to some years later, and we find June (approximately 9 years old), living with a white trash family that fulfills all of the stereotypes that go along with that archetype: A fat, slovenly father who’s never seen without a beer in his hand, a mom who wears clothes that are far too tight, and might be working as a prostitute, and siblings who make it their job to torture little June every chance they get. They even live in a dilapidated trailer in the midst of a even more dilapidated trailer park. How June ended up there isn’t explained, but her case worker, Mr. Emmanuel (Eddie Jemison), promises June that he’s going to put her in a better place soon because he knows what can happen when she gets “upset”.
>
> Not long after, June’s foster family is throwing a BBQ party filled with more stereotypical white trash attendees. June is silently playing with her favorite doll when two boys decide to taunt her by throwing firecrackers at her. When she doesn’t respond to the firecrackers as hoped, one of them gets up and tries to snatch up her doll as he berates her. June finally responds by summoning up a strong wind, as her eyes turn black and she emits a loud, banshee like scream that knocks out everyone at the BBQ. Soon afterwards, Mr. Emmanuel gets June into a new foster home with a couple who can’t have children, Dave (Casper Van Dien) & Lily (Victoria Pratt) Anderson. The Andersen’s are a loving couple, with a nice home and plenty of love to give to June, and it seems that June is going to do very well in her new surroundings. But June doesn’t say too much (the only sound she’s uttered up to this point was the scream at the trailer park), and she spends a lot of time drawing nightmarish images of her new family, with the dad crossed out. She also draws pictures of something she calls Aery (referred to as “Aer” by everyone else), her imaginary friend. But the Andersen’s soon discover that Aery isn’t as imaginary as June says she is…

### Trailer

Found with a search for `2015 horror film orphan girl demon`